# How would you prepare students for "Alice and Bob" Putnam problems?

Tags: undergraduate-education, math-contests, games

Every year the [Putnam Competition](https://maa.org/math-competitions/william-lowell-putnam-mathematical-competition) features at least one question that describes Alice and Bob playing game, and asks for one player's winning strategy or something similar. Since these questions are usually more comprehensible than the others on the Putnam, many of my students who compete submit responses to these questions, but their submissions usually don't score.

How should I teach students to better answer these types of questions? What proof-writing techniques should I demonstrate to them? What problem-solving (thought) pattern(s) should I encourage them to adopt to help them translate their understanding of the game through "playing some examples" to writing a proof?

[Here's the MathSE analog of this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4872433/167197)

---

For example, [problem A6 from the 2023 Putnam Competition](https://maa.org/sites/default/files/Programs/2023Putnam_A.pdf):

> Alice and Bob play a game in which they take turns choosing integers from $1$ to $n$. Before any integers are
> chosen, Bob selects a goal of "odd" or "even". On the first turn, Alice chooses one of the $n$ integers. On
> the second turn, Bob chooses one of the remaining integers. They continue alternately choosing one of the
> integers that has not yet been chosen, until the $n$th turn, which is forced and ends the game. Bob wins if the
> parity of $\{k : \text{the number $k$ was chosen on the $k$th turn}\}$ matches his goal. For which values of $n$ does Bob
> have a winning strategy?

Comment: The base plan is to have an *Alice and Bob* day, curate some of the past problems of this type with solutions that don't appear to have any inspired details, and roll from there, but I was wondering if there were any specific direction that would help them first.

Answer (score 2):

All games with numbers: teach them to start with very small numbers, like here with n=3,4,5 may be some more they find a rule and then only they start to generalize and prove.

Answer (score 2):

To give your students well rounded training, I suggest you use puzzles from as many different sources as possible.

As an example, here are some problems you might use (they are from Leningrad Mathematical Olympiads).

1982:

Anna and Boris play a game with a stack of 100 counters. Anna goes first, and moves alternate thereafter. In each move, a player divides a stack of at least two counters into two smaller piles. The loser is the player without a move, when each stack consists of exactly one counter. Prove that Anna must win this game.

1987:

Anna and Boris play a game on a 9 × 9 chessboard. Anna goes first and turns alternate thereafter. In each move, Anna puts a red counter on a vacant square while Boris puts a blue counter on a vacant square. When the board is completely filled, a row with more red counters than blue counters is called a red row, and a blue row otherwise. Red and blue columns are similarly defined. The score for Anna is the sum of the numbers of red rows and red columns while that for Boris is the sum of the numbers of blue rows and blue columns. What is the highest possible score for Anna?

1990:

Anna and Boris play a game starting with the number 1234. Anna goes first, and turns alternate thereafter. In each turn, the player subtracts from the number one of its non-zero digits. A player wins if the number is reduced to 0. Who has a winning strategy, Anna or Boris?